# How to retain the value of a variable when the UIGestureRecognizer class is called repeatedly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm calling a `UIGestureRecognizer` class on an image view and i'm setting value for an associated label when `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` is called.

If the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` is called for the second time , the value for the same label is set with the initial value again.

**How do i retain the same value even after when the state is ended and started again?**

Please do let me know...Here is the code below,

```
-(void) longPress: (UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{     
  NSInteger intValue;

 UIGestureRecognizerState state = [gestureRecognizer state];

switch (state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
        NSLog(@"LongPress UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
        beginPositionlocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"%f", beginPositionlocation.y);

        volumeLabelOnLongPress = nil;

        for (UIView* view in gestureRecognizer.view.subviews) {
            if (view.tag == kVolumeLblTag) {
                volumeLabelOnLongPress = (UILabel *)view;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

            endPositionlocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

            NSLog(@"%f", beginPositionlocation.y);
            NSLog(@"%f", endPositionlocation.y);

                intValue = (NSInteger) roundf(beginPositionlocation.y-endPositionlocation.y);

        if (volumeLabelOnLongPress!=nil) {
            [volumeLabelOnLongPress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intValue]];

              if ((intValue >= 10 ) && (intValue <=20)){
                [volumeLabelOnLongPress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intValue]];

            }

              else if ((intValue >= 21 ) && (intValue <=30)){
                [volumeLabelOnLongPress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intValue]];

            }
       }

        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
        NSLog(@"LongPress UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
       endPositionlocation = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
        beginPositionlocation = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

        break;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank You,

Comment: What is the problem? Just track the state and do not override variable in certain conditions

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: Please do check the above posted code...

Comment: Make the value `static`

Comment: @Azat: The variable value ("intValue" in above code) is set again to the initial value once the changed state is called. How do i retain that value each time the above method is called...??

Comment: @Lefteris: No the value can't be static since i need to change the value based on user interaction.

Comment: @user4886142 Store the values in an array, or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: I said `static` not `const` (constant) Read what a `static` variable is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Comment: Yes because it is so-called automatic variable, it is created every time you enter that function. Make it `ivar` or `property`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) longPress: (UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{     
  static NSInteger intValue;

 UIGestureRecognizerState state = [gestureRecognizer state];

switch (state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
        NSLog(@"LongPress UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
        beginPositionlocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"%f", beginPositionlocation.y);

        volumeLabelOnLongPress = nil;

        for (UIView* view in gestureRecognizer.view.subviews) {
            if (view.tag == kVolumeLblTag) {
                volumeLabelOnLongPress = (UILabel *)view;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

            endPositionlocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

            NSLog(@"%f", beginPositionlocation.y);
            NSLog(@"%f", endPositionlocation.y);

                intValue = (NSInteger) roundf(beginPositionlocation.y-endPositionlocation.y);

        if (volumeLabelOnLongPress!=nil) {
            [volumeLabelOnLongPress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intValue]];

              if ((intValue >= 10 ) && (intValue <=20)){
                [volumeLabelOnLongPress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intValue]];

            }

              else if ((intValue >= 21 ) && (intValue <=30)){
                [volumeLabelOnLongPress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intValue]];

            }
       }

        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
        NSLog(@"LongPress UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
       endPositionlocation = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
        beginPositionlocation = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

        break;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing changed from your code, is that I made the intValue `static`

Comment: Yes i got that , but it means that the value can be initialized again but how to retain the previously changed value when UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged  is called?

Comment: Did you try my code? As long as the whole class is not initialized again, the intValue will retain the previous value. That's the way `static` variables work

Comment: No sorry i did not work out .. And now i have changed the switch statement to an if-else since 'state' is an enum which cannot be handled by switch..

Comment: Are you re-initializing the class every time?

Comment: Yes i need to ... thats the reason i'm telling that it has no effect if i use it as statix...

Comment: Then you need to either: A. Save the value in the `NSUserDefaults` and read it from there every time, B. Add an instance Variable in your AppDelegate and use that to store the value, C. Make the class a singleton class, D. Create a singleton class that stores global data and save it as an iVar there